# GroupBy and Sum on a DataTable

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, group-by, sum

I am using LINQ in VB on a datatable to filter my results.

```
m_oDataTable.Columns.Add("Name1", GetType(String))
m_oDataTable.Columns.Add("Name2", GetType(String))
m_oDataTable.Columns.Add("Time", GetType(Double))
```

I am trying to filter the datatable by `Name1` or `Name2` based on user selection.

```
groupBy = "Name1" 
'groupBy = "Name2"
```

I grouped my data but I was unable to `Sum` the desired field.

```
Dim test =  From tab In m_oDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            Group tab By groupDt = tab.Field(Of String)(groupBy) Into Group
            Select Group

'Getting Error
Dim test2 = From tab In m_oDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            Group tab By groupDt = tab.Field(Of String)(groupBy) Into Group
            Select New With 
            {
             .Grp = Key, ' Error in this line(Key is a type, cannot be used as a expression)
             .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("Time").ToString()))
            }
```

I tried in c# and got the desired result. But have no luck with VB :(

```
var test = from tab in m_oDataTable.AsEnumerable()
           group tab by tab.Field<string>(groupBy)
                 into groupDt
                 select new
                 {
                     Group = groupDt.Key,
                     Sum = groupDt.Sum(r => double.Parse(r["Time"].ToString()))
                 };
```

How to achieve this in VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure why but VB.Net does not support .Key on query expression syntax. You actually define the key variable in the query. You are trying to use a variable "Key" which has not been defined. Instead you need to use they key you defined in the query (groupDt).

Change one small line and it should work...

```
Select New With 
                {
                 .Grp = groupDt,
                 .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("Time").ToString()))
                }
```

OR you can use fluent syntax:

```
Dim test2 = Table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Item("Name1")).Select(Function(group) New With {.Grp = group.Key, .Sum = group.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("Time").ToString()))})
```